# Need to extract text from within first curly brackets

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have strings that look like this

```
{/CSDC} CHOC SHELL DIP COLOR {17}
```

I need to extract the value in the first swirly brackets. In the above example it would be

```
/CSDC
```

So far i have this code which is not working

```
Dim matchCode = Regex.Matches(txtItems.Text, "/\{(.+?)\}/")
Dim itemCode As String
If matchCode.Count > 0 Then
   itemCode = matchCode(0).Value
End If
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Vb.net Regex" and such. That's what the tags are for. Also, though you may be running this code in an ASP.NET application, the question itself has nothing to do with ASP.NET, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that you are confusing your regular expression syntax between different languages.

In languages like Javascript, Perl, Ruby and others, you create a regular expression object by using the `/regex/` notation.

In .NET, when you instantiate a `Regex` object, you pass it a string of the regular expression, which is delimited by quotes, not slashes. So it is of the form `"regex"`.

So try removing the leading and trailing `/` from your string and see how you go.

This may not be the whole problem, but it is at least part of it.

Comment: Thanks very much. Removing the "/" from beginning and end helped.

Comment: I should mention that this code helps me find the code with the swirly brackets. This I can easily take care of with replace.

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting the whole string instead of just the 1st value? Regular expressions are greedy by default so .Net is trying to grab the largest matching string.

Try this:

```
Dim matchCode = Regex.Matches(txtItems.Text, "\{[^}]*\}")
Dim itemCode As String
If matchCode.Count > 0 Then
   itemCode = matchCode(0).Groups(0).Value
End If
```

Edited: I've tried this in Linqpad and it worked.

Comment: Like @GregL said, you were confusing the syntax. I didn't notice that in my first answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using a capture group..  so try matchCode(0).Groups(0).Value

Also, remove the /\ from the beginning of the pattern and remove the trailing /